# regex 1 character and space only

Tags: c++, regex

Hi i am learning regex..
  I was trying to make a regex expression for following conditon:

1. any letter in the sequence given below - C-MPSTV-XZ condition is that it should not be repeated.
2. This letter can have one blank space in front or back ie it can be " C" or "C "

   [C-MPSTV-XZ{1} ]{2}

I was trying the above expression {1} expected one character only and space after that allowing one space only. At the end of string i put {2} to get only 2 character .

I was expecting regex_match to be false for input "XX" but its not working.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to match two-character sequences where one (but not both) can be space, i.e. 'XX', 'X ', ' X' but not '  ' (two spaces), is that correct?

Comment: Hi Alex you are correct but at the same time i dont want two letters even. So the match should return true for - " X" , "X " but false for "XX" "  " .

Comment: And what do you want for "X" - also true? Also, what about non repeating letters, like "XC"?

Comment: @Alex1985  - Thanks for your time..I require only single letter if i provide this condition of matching only a single letter. Then XC should be false.

Answer (score 2):

`\s?[C-MPSTV-XZ]\s?`.  If you are using `std::regex_match`,
you shouldn't need anything else, since `regex_match` requires
a match over the entire string.

Answer (score 2):

Your posted regex will match two characters which are both not spaces, because you're asking for any two from inside the character class. You're also going to accept `{`, `1` and `}` as characters because quantifiers act as literal characters inside a character class.

The simple alternative is to just spell out the two conditions explicitly:

```
( [C-MPRSTV-XZ]|[C-MPRSTV-XZ] )
```

This assumes that your regex engine is treating whitespace within regexes as significant. If not, or if you don't like that, replace the spaces with a suitable escape sequence.